# usage of "name" as transitive verb

Tags: grammar

I was having a look on usage of name as verb [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/name). I could understand the meaning of following correct usages.

- He named his dog Shandy.
- He could not name his attacker.
- Name a pet animal.

I want to ask whether following usages of name as verb is grammatically correct.

USAGE 1:

```
Can you name me a pet animal?
```

If yes, which of the following describes the situation.

```
1. a name of any pet animal is being asked.
2. The interrogator is asking his name to be changed to a pet animal.
```

USAGE 2:

```
Sandy could not name me his attacker?
```

If yes, which of the following describes the situation.

```
1. Sandy could not tell me the name of his attacker.
2. Sandy did not accuse me as his attacker.
```

Comment: The *me* hasn't much business being there unless the naming is of *me* in the first place :)

Comment: It serves the same purpose as the "me" in "Could you draw me a tree?" or "Could you sing me a song?" There is an implied "for" in front of it. This is similar to the implied "to" before "you" in "I'm going to give you a gift" or the implied "to" before "Dad" in "I wrote Dad a letter". In some circumstances the preposition before a dative may be omitted.

Answer (score 4):

**Usage 1:**

> Can you name me a pet animal?

This is correct. At least it is not uncommon among colloquial native speakers in North America. You probably won't see this wording in a textbook, but then you'd rarely see the first person in a textbook anyway.

> If yes, which of the following describes the situation.

Neither. The questioner is asking for a *type* of animal that is a pet. *Dog* would be an acceptable answer. *Buddy* (a common name for a dog) would not.

**Usage 2:**

> Sandy could not name me his attacker?

This is incorrect. You could rephrase this to *Could Sandy not name his attacker?*, in which case I am asking whether Sandy was able to provide the *name* of the attacker.